# Android Studio Map Activity app Show current location

Tags: android-activity, android-studio, location, maps

I have this code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {

            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            if (mMap != null) {

                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

It looks good, but when I running my app, and trying to press button which should show my current location its nothing happens can someone help me for this problem ? pls !!!.

Comment: Where are you using button click??...onButton Click only you want to show current location..??

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get google map api key from google developer site , for do that login to https://developers.google.com/ with your google account and find google apis , then add maps api and get your own api key (its free )
then you should add a new google maps activity from new menu (in android studio app) , this automatic build you an activity and add google_maps_api.xml and also add permission and meta-data to your manifest file

use your google map api key in manifest xml file

```
        <meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your_google_maps_key" />
```

and also google_maps_api.xml file

```
<resources>

<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false"    templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
    your_google_maps_key
</string>
</resources>
```

now you can use google maps on your application

now you need to setup your maps with this method :

for finding your location you need to save your location's coordinates to Location variable

```
    private void setUpMap() {

       if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
         mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
         // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
         if (mMap != null) {
            LocationManager lManager; 
            lManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 
            Criteria cr = new Criteria(); 
            // find best provider for location services
            String provider = lManager.getBestProvider(cr, true);
            // get your last khown location 
            Location location = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            // set update freq for location updating 
            lManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this); 
            // save your location to LatLng variable
            LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),             location.getLongitude());
            // zoom to your location - 12 is zoom size
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition,  12));
            // add your custom marker to map
            mMap.addMarker(new       MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).title("\u200e" + "Me")).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
         }
        }
     }
```

then call setUpMap() on your activity onCreate

Comment: ok thanks for help guysm but anyway i cant understand where i need to put these codes, can you guys mby give me all the code?

Answer (score 0):

run the following code on button press:

```
 Location location = map.getMyLocation();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the below code also:

Add a **mapview** in `xml` layout as

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then in your code (Here i am using **Fragmnet**)

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

  MapView gMapView;
  GoogleMap gMap = null;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);

    gMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    gMapView.getMapAsync(this);  //this is the main line which will make a callback when map is ready

    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    gMap = map;
    gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
            LatLng(your_latlng), 12));
  }
}
```